# how to link foreign key with to models

Tags: django, django-models

I have Class called Item , and this item some time linked to Category and some time linked to SubCategory ,

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='sub_category')
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(<<-- Category or subCategory -->>, on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
```

I need to link Item with tow models , so i can use sort_by rank field

Comment: You can add two foreign keys and check for their presence?

Comment: yes but i can't use order_by

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CAT_TYPES = [
        ('M', 'Main Category'),
        ('S', 'Sub Category'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CAT_TYPES, blank=True, default='M')
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...)
```

views.py

```
def something(request):
    main_categories = Categories.objects.filter(type='M')
    sub_categories = Categories.objects.filter(type='S')
```

Comment: Thanks man , But how can I link sub category with category 
you missed this line     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='sub_category')

Comment: You don't link another sub category, you delete it. You have field "type" which tells you if category is main or sub category. That's correct way to model database and I would choose for that problem you have.